# Counting Chains of Strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a string column `col1` containing product ids, such as:

```
id1/id3/id4/id5
id2/id3/id6/id4/id10
id1/id7/id8
id10/id3/id14/id21/id34
```

where `id1/id3/id4` represents that product id4 is within product id3 which is within product id1, how would you get the unique number of product ids stored within product id3? In this case it's 7:

```
[id4, id5, id6, id10, id14, id21, id34]
```

I have a sketch of a pretty complex solution using arrays by splitting the col1, reversing the result array and getting the cardinality up until the index of 'John'.

But it looks pretty complicated and was wondering if there is some other quicker "hack".

Comment: Please read the text of the tag [tag:sql], it contains: **"....... and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used."**

Comment: For a general SQL answer: You should not put multiple values in one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a start, you could do this, and then apply your rules to the result this is giving:

```sql
SELECT
  R,
  t2,
  array_position(string_to_array(col1,'/'), t2) as P
FROM (
  SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) R,
     col1
   FROM 
     table1) t1 
  CROSS JOIN unnest(string_to_array(col1,'/')) t2
```

results:

| r | t2 | p |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id10 | 1 |
| 1 | id3 | 2 |
| 1 | id14 | 3 |
| 1 | id21 | 4 |
| 1 | id34 | 5 |
| 2 | id1 | 1 |
| 2 | id3 | 2 |
| 2 | id4 | 3 |
| 2 | id5 | 4 |
| 3 | id1 | 1 |
| 3 | id7 | 2 |
| 3 | id8 | 3 |
| 4 | id2 | 1 |
| 4 | id3 | 2 |
| 4 | id6 | 3 |
| 4 | id4 | 4 |
| 4 | id10 | 5 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/D2SkfJv5)